# gpkg file conversion

Tags: gdal-translate, geopackage, gdaladdo

I have a gpkg that is populated exclusively by .jpeg files. I am attempting to 
use the gdaladdo to add overviews into that gpkg. However, gdaladdo adds some of them as .jpeg, and adds the rest as .png. I was wondering if there is any way to configure gdaladdo so that it will only add the overviews as 
.jpeg files.

The commands I run are:

```
gdal_translate -of GPKG myTiff.tif myGpkg.gpkg -co 
TILING_SCHEME=InspireCRS84Quad -co ZOOM_LEVEL_STRATEGY=LOWER -co 
TILE_FORMAT=JPEG 

gdaladdo myGpkg.gpkg 2 4 8 16 32 64 128
```